# Custom ListView + getView method

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I need help with custom adapter with getView() method. When adapter create a list in getView() method called every time rendering like `holder.textEpisode.setTextColor()` etc. This gives heavy load and the list begins to slow down.
Please help me solve this problem. Thanks!

```
public class myAdapterDouble extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

private int[] colorWhite = new int[] { -0x1 };
private int[] colors = new int[] { -0x1, -0x242425 };
private int[] colorBlack = new int[] { -0x1000000 };
private int[] colorTransparent = new int[] { android.R.color.transparent };
private LayoutInflater lInflater;
private ArrayList<Order> data;
private Order o;
private DisplayImageOptions options;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private ImageLoaderConfiguration config;
private Context ctx;
private Typeface tf;

public myAdapterDouble(Context c, int listItem, ArrayList<Order> data) {
super(c, listItem, data);
lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
this.data = data;
ctx = c;

tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "meiryo.ttc");

imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.no_image)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image).cacheOnDisc()
        .cacheInMemory().build();

config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(c.getApplicationContext())
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
        .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)  // 2 Mb
        .memoryCacheExtraOptions(100, 100)
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO).enableLogging()
        .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
}

SharedPreferences sharedPref;
boolean posters, fixFont;
float headerSize, timeSize, dateSize;
int imageWSize;

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

ViewHolder holder = null;
o = data.get(position);

sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
posters = sharedPref.getBoolean("poster", true);
fixFont = sharedPref.getBoolean("fix_font", false);

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.double_list_item, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.textName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);   
    if (fixFont) {
        try {
            holder.textName.setTypeface(tf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            holder.textName.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    holder.textEpisode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    String width = sharedPref.getString("image_width", "70");
    imageWSize = Integer.parseInt(width); // ширина
    final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int px = (int) (imageWSize*scale + 0.5f);

    holder.img.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    holder.img.getLayoutParams().width = px;
    if(imageWSize == 0) {
        holder.img.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    }
    holder.img.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

headerSize = Float.parseFloat(sharedPref.getString("headsize", "20"));
holder.textName.setTextSize(headerSize); // размер названия
timeSize = Float.parseFloat(sharedPref.getString("timesize", "15"));
holder.textEpisode.setTextSize(timeSize); // размер времени

if (posters) {
    holder.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    try {
        imageLoader.displayImage(o.getLink(), holder.img, options);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    holder.img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

holder.img.setTag(o);
holder.textName.setText(o.getTextName());
holder.textEpisode.setText(o.getTextEpisode());
holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

if (o.getTextEpisode().toString().contains(ctx.getString(R.string.final_ep))) { 
    String finaleColor = sharedPref.getString("finale_color", "1");
    if (finaleColor.contains("default")) {
        holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2E64FE"));
    }
    if (finaleColor.contains("yelow")) {
        holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }
    if (finaleColor.contains("red")) {
        holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    if (finaleColor.contains("green")) {
        holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    if (finaleColor.contains("white")) {
        holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    if (finaleColor.contains("gray")) {
        holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    }           
} else {
    holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2E64FE"));
}

String chooseColor = sharedPref.getString("colorList", "");
if (chooseColor.contains("white")) {
    int colorPos = position % colorWhite.length;
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorWhite[colorPos]);
}
if (chooseColor.contains("black")) {
    int colorPos = position % colorBlack.length;
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorBlack[colorPos]);
    holder.textName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
}
if (chooseColor.contains("whitegray")) {
    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
}
if (chooseColor.contains("transparent")) {
    int colorPos = position % colorTransparent.length;
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorTransparent[colorPos]);
}

return convertView;
}
```

Comment: It is the behavior of Listview to recycle views in order to save memory. Listview implemented with lots of recycling mechanisms. It will allocate memory for the currently visible items, so getView() will be called every time

Comment: Can somehow resolve this?

Comment: You need to use LinearLayout with scrollview, but it will cause memory problems when your list is too big

Comment: My list can contain more than 100 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getView() method will be called every time when u do a scroll for loading next items.

```
sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
posters = sharedPref.getBoolean("poster", true);
fixFont = sharedPref.getBoolean("fix_font", false);
```

This should slow the scroll since every time it need to read and parse the preference.

Have all those preferences been loaded once as some variables.

If that still does not solved the problem that try [Method Profiling](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) and check whats Incl% for the getView Method and see which methods is taking more cpu usage in getView.

**EDITED**

```
public class myAdapterDouble extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {
    private int[] colorWhite = new int[] { -0x1 };
    private int[] colors = new int[] { -0x1, -0x242425 };
    private int[] colorBlack = new int[] { -0x1000000 };
    private int[] colorTransparent = new int[] { android.R.color.transparent };
    private LayoutInflater lInflater;
    private ArrayList<Order> data;
    private Order o;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private ImageLoaderConfiguration config;
    private Context ctx;
    private Typeface tf;


    boolean posters, fixFont;
    float headerSize, timeSize, dateSize;
    int imageWSize;
    private String finaleColor;
    private String chooseColor;
    private String final_ep;

    public myAdapterDouble(Context c, int listItem, ArrayList<Order> data) {
        super(c, listItem, data);
        lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.data = data;
        ctx = c;

        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "meiryo.ttc");

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showStubImage(R.drawable.no_image).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image).cacheOnDisc().cacheInMemory().build();

        config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(c.getApplicationContext()).threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2).memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
                // 2 Mb
                .memoryCacheExtraOptions(100, 100).denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory().discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator()).tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                .enableLogging().build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref;

        sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        posters = sharedPref.getBoolean("poster", true);
        fixFont = sharedPref.getBoolean("fix_font", false);

        String width = sharedPref.getString("image_width", "70");
        imageWSize = Integer.parseInt(width); // ширина
        headerSize = Float.parseFloat(sharedPref.getString("headsize", "20"));
        timeSize = Float.parseFloat(sharedPref.getString("timesize", "15"));

        finaleColor = sharedPref.getString("finale_color", "1");
        chooseColor = sharedPref.getString("colorList", "");
        final_ep = ctx.getString(R.string.final_ep);
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        o = data.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.double_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            if (fixFont) {
                try {
                    holder.textName.setTypeface(tf);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else {
                try {
                    holder.textName.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            holder.textEpisode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);


            final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int px = (int) (imageWSize * scale + 0.5f);

            holder.img.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            holder.img.getLayoutParams().width = px;
            if (imageWSize == 0) {
                holder.img.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            }
            holder.img.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.textName.setTextSize(headerSize); // размер названия

        holder.textEpisode.setTextSize(timeSize); // размер времени

        if (posters) {
            holder.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            try {
                imageLoader.displayImage(o.getLink(), holder.img, options);
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            holder.img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.img.setTag(o);
        holder.textName.setText(o.getTextName());
        holder.textEpisode.setText(o.getTextEpisode());
        holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


        if (o.getTextEpisode().toString().contains()) {

            if (finaleColor.contains("default")) {
                holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2E64FE"));
            }
            if (finaleColor.contains("yelow")) {
                holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            if (finaleColor.contains("red")) {
                holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if (finaleColor.contains("green")) {
                holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            if (finaleColor.contains("white")) {
                holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            if (finaleColor.contains("gray")) {
                holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
        }
        else {
            holder.textEpisode.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2E64FE"));
        }


        if (chooseColor.contains("white")) {
            int colorPos = position % colorWhite.length;
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorWhite[colorPos]);
        }
        if (chooseColor.contains("black")) {
            int colorPos = position % colorBlack.length;
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorBlack[colorPos]);
            holder.textName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }
        if (chooseColor.contains("whitegray")) {
            int colorPos = position % colors.length;
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
        }
        if (chooseColor.contains("transparent")) {
            int colorPos = position % colorTransparent.length;
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorTransparent[colorPos]);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Have all those preferences been loaded once as some variables.` Can you post sample for this? I'm beginner in Java

Comment: Update. Need sample for better understanding

Comment: Well, i edit my code. Code work but this is not what I'm looking for. Sorry. Perhaps I'm wrong to expressed. The problem is different: app displays a list, I press on any of the items and I get into the details of. Repeat this actions 5-10 times Android begins slow down. Perhaps this is a memory leak? It is my main question.

Comment: It may not be due to memory leak. If there is a memory leak it might lead with a OutOfMemoryException. From my observation, I think some of your methods has more cpu usage. Try using Method Profiling, that will give u which method is using more cpu.

Comment: You are right. App slow down, but I'm not get OutOfMemoryException. I will be try use Method Profiling. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

try like this instead of `viewholder` this works perfectly for me.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View v = convertView;
sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
posters = sharedPref.getBoolean("poster", true);
fixFont = sharedPref.getBoolean("fix_font", false);

if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.double_list_item, null);
}

TextView textName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
if (fixFont){
   try {
        textName.setTypeface(tf);
   } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}else {
   try {
        textName.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
   } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
return super.getView(position, v, parent);
}
};
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This is correct code? Without ViewHolder? And i think `LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` must be called in the constructor once for better performance. Right?

Comment: No need Azat. Try it. If you didn't get the answer as you wanted then try to add that line in your constructor and then let me know if find any difference.